# angular 2 optimal way to map incoming api json into a array of class objects

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm working with Angular 2. I'm trying to figure out the correct way to map a incoming json object into a array of class

**./book.ts**

```
export class book{
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public title: string,
    public publication_date: string){}
}
```

**./book.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { RequestOptions, URLSearchParams,  QueryEncoder, Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Trip } from './trip';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  fetchbooks(): Observable<book[]>{
    return this.http.get('some_url')
    .map((res: Response) => <book[]>res.json().books);
  }
}
```

but the

> fetchbooks()

doesn't map the incoming json to the book class object.. so i cant do type check.
is there any other way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your thoughts on this matter are correct. Because the objects are created by JSON.parse it really makes no sense to use a class to describe their shape. The instance of tests will of course fail and it results in a misleading API.

However there is a simple solution. Typescript has a notion interfaces which are used to describe the shape of various API but have no run-time manifestation. This is a perfect use case for an interface and not a class. Please note that interfaces in typescript are not at all related to interfaces in languages such as Java.

I am aware that my advice is in conflict with the official style guide on this point. In general it makes some good recommendations but it is wrong on this one. Do not use classes to describe the shape of objects returned to remote services via JSON.

You actually don't need to test the types of the objects coming back if you know and trust the end point that is serving them. Your current approach which asserts the type of the response using a generic is a good approach. Just use interface instead of a class.

you can of course associate specific objects with specific interface types. You could correlate this based on server-side serialized fields so you have the option if you need to but you still wouldn't want to use a class for that on the client.

Comment: thanks alot for the reply. The reason i decided to use class, inorder to specify strictNullChecks and after getting the api json data map to the class object i can use the class object for other operation in the app. Also i wanted runtime type cast check

Comment: `strictNullChecks` are awesome. They have nothing to do with classes and are as applicable to interfaces.

Comment: if i use interface something like this: 
`<Book>value.json();`
This will not result in any errors if the server sends bad objects because of 2 reasons.

At compile time the transpiler does not know what the server will send.
At runtime all type information is erased since everything gets compiled to javascript.
so how to do the structure and type check??

Comment: Using classes doesn't automatically validate. If you want to validate the structure of responses, you will need to write validation logic. In that case you could do so in a constructor or factory function that takes the JSON response.

Comment: "so how to do the structure and type check??" this is not possible. A class's type is as erased as an interface.

Comment: so during runtime anything can be assigned to class variable. Even the `strictNullChecks` will not hold any good during runtime.  correct? 
so no library can solve this na?

Comment: You need to define a function, which could be a class constructor, or just a simple function, that  performs runtime validation of the values returned by the service call. The function can contain whatever validation you deem appropriate but may not include TypeScript types. Those are for compile time validation only.

Comment: StrictNullChecks are a TypeScript compile time check. If you want to ensure a value that came from a non typescript source, such as a web service, is not null or undefined at runtime, you need to test for that.